# Downgrade PHP to PHP5.2?

Tags: 11.04, apache2, php, downgrade

I want to install PHP 5.2 in Ubuntu 11.04 , I had some script that did that thing good but only on Ubuntu 9, anyone has a script / instructions how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The first way** is using Andphe's PPA. This method is described [here](http://www.alexweber.com.br/en/tutorials/how-install-php-52-ubuntu-1010-maverick-and-1104-natty).

1. Uninstall all PHP packages.
2. Add the repo by executing `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:andphe/php && sudo apt-get update`
3. Open Synaptic. Go to Settings -> Repositories. Select the repository we have just added and click "Edit..." Replace "natty" with "maverick". Click "Ok" then "Close".
4. Click the reload button.
5. Now find the php5 package. Press Ctrl + E. Select the version from the PPA. In the main menu, click Package -> Lock Version.
6. Repeat step 5 for other PHP packages.
7. Apply the changes.

**N.B. start with "libapache2-mod-php5", "php5-common", "php5-cli" and then the rest**

**The second way** is attempting to install packages built for Lucid. They can be found [here](http://thejibe.com/blog/10/5/php-5210-debs-ubuntu-104-lucid).
Just download the packages, dpkg -i them all, and then [pin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) all of them. I will not go into detail because I think that the first way is better.

**The third way** is installing from source. [This guide](http://earthviaradio.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/compiling-php-5-2-for-ubuntu-10-10/) seems quite good. This is your fallback route.

Comment: I may be reading the script wrongly... but wouldnt that leave your sources list as karmic - wouldnt you need to reset it back to natty after the install?

Comment: @fossfreedom Wait, yes...

Comment: this could become a very good answer if you can highlight in the answer the relevant parts of the links that answer the question.  Usually you just link back to the "source" to indicate where you got the answer.

Comment: i run this script: http://pastebin.com/C41eXyKi , how can i revert those actions and do the install as you told me?

Comment: @Amir Ashkenazi Just remove all the PHP packages, then go to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and remove karmic.list.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to try and work out why the PHP script doesn't work with PHP 5.3. It could just be down to some deprecated code that can easily be replaced

The PHP manual has a section on migrating from 5.2 to 5.3:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.php

Comment: yeah, but the issue that is the most servers (shared hosting) are still have 5.2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the server edition:

1. add [Andphe's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~andphe/+archive/ppa).
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5=5.2.14.dfsg.1-0ubuntu0~andpheppa1

In general using = lets you install the version you prefer; check the available versions using apt-cache policy .

Do not forget to create /etc/apt/preferences.d/php5-5-2-14

```
Package: php5-cli libapache2-mod-php5 php5-common
Pin: version 5.2*
Pin-Priority: 1001
```