# How can I run php 5.2 on 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, package-management, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to downgrade PHP from 5.3.x to 5.2.x](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82731/how-to-downgrade-php-from-5-3-x-to-5-2-x)

For drupal servers, I used to install 10.04 (lucid) + php 5.2 (karmic).
Now that karmic is gone, I don't know where to take php 5.2 any more.

Is there any proven replacement/alternative to this approach?

cheers !!