# How do i install PHP5.2 on Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to downgrade PHP from 5.3.x to 5.2.x](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82731/how-to-downgrade-php-from-5-3-x-to-5-2-x)

How do i install PHP5.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 server? Do you know any PPA for that?

Thanks,