# How can I install php 5.2 in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, php

I wish to install a "legacy" php application (magento commerce 1.3) into a oneiric server. All the ppa's I've found hold packages for previous ubuntu versions.

I've tried to recompile php myself but the gd prerequisites are missing.

The same question for 10.10 is [answered here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61101/downgrade-php-to-php5-2)

Comment: I hate answering myself :-) since I didn't find any way to use the binary packages I resolved to [compile php on my own](http://lrkwz.blogspot.com/2012/02/installing-magento-130-on-ubuntu-1110.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all php-related packages use the [historical repositories from old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://goo.gl/TvMkc) for the karmic Ubuntu release to downgrade to php 5.2

I created a script solution here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9201854&postcount=6

it adds the histroical sources to a file /etc/apt/preferences.d/php5_2
that locks all php-related packages to karmic.

your system will stil stay on the actual release (11.10) onnly php will be taken from the old release